# Angular libraries testing issue in gitlab CI

Tags: angular, gitlab, continuous-integration, karma-runner

I'm really exhausted of searching for this problem.

I have an Angular project ver-8 of libraries and I implemented test for these.
These are running fine on local machine but it throws error in gitlab CI.
This just runs first library test but throws error for the rest.

This is my karma.conf.js file:
[karma.conf.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSPbU.jpg)

This is the test result in gitlab CI:
[Gitlab CI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P7ir.png)